# Python: IndexError: list index out of range - accessing y values for PyGame objects

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list which stores the y coordinate of a contact object in a list so that I can then access a contact's information relative its y position on the screen. I'm using PyGame if this is useful information.

Printing list is fine and returns the correct values, but when I'm trying to access the list in the Main Event Loop I get the above error when iterating through the list with a `for` loop.

Here is the code for the appending of y values to my list:

```
class MainPage(Page):
    ...

    def printContacts(self):
        addressBook = AddressBook()
        addressBook.contactsList
        addressBook.contactsList.sort(key = lambda c: (c.lastName, c.firstName) if c.lastName else (c.firstName, ""))
        contactFont = pygame.font.SysFont("trebuchet ms", 18)
        global indexedContacts
        indexedContacts = {}
        global yIndex
        yIndex = [] #List to append y values to
        y = 20

        for (key, g) in groupby(addressBook.contactsList, lambda c: c.lastName[0] if c.lastName else c.firstName[0]):
            groupName = contactFont.render(key, True, (171,0,0))
            self.intermediate2.blit(groupName, (5, y))
            pygame.draw.line(self.intermediate2, (0,0,0), (5,(y+20)), (320, (y+20)), 1)
            y += 30

            for i in g:
                name = i.firstName + " " + i.lastName
                textName = contactFont.render(name, True, (0,0,0))
                pygame.draw.line(self.intermediate2, (210,210,210), (5,(y+20)), (320, (y+20)), 1)
                self.intermediate2.blit(textName, (5, y))
                indexedContacts[(y+72)] = i
                yIndex.append((y+72)) #Appends current value to list
                y += 30
```

Here is the event code that's returning the error:

```
for i in yIndex:
    if y >= (yIndex[i] - 10) and y <= (yIndex[i] + 20): #Error here
        y = yIndex[i]
        if y in indexedContacts:
            page = EditPage()
            page.style()
            page.contactFields()
            break
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem, `yIndex[i]` generates the error as `i` becomes each item in the `yIndex` list, like [eddieferetro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382300/eddieferetro/) explained in his answer.

So, in essence, the code should be:

```
for i in yIndex:
    if y >= (i - 10) and y <= (i + 20):
        if i in indexedContacts:
            page = EditPage()
            page.style()
            page.contactFields()
            break
```

Basically, a very common error.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in yIndex:
```

Gives to you the values of yIndex in i....

i is not an index, is the element itself. Like in java:

```
for (Item item: arrayOfItems)
```

In yout case yIndex is an array of integers so the error cames like a index out of range exception

To get the indexes you should write:

```
for i, val in enumerate(yIndex):
```

In your case you want:

```
for y in yIndex:
    if yo >= (y - 10) and yo <= (y + 20): #Error here
        yo = y
        if yo in indexedContacts:
            page = EditPage()
            page.style()
            page.contactFields()
            break
    else:
        continue
```

i will be the index and yIndex the value